# a and b both divide c and are coprime; does ab then also divide c?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, coprime

I believe that I intuitively understand that if $a$ divides $c$ and $b$ divides $c$ and if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then their product $ab$ must also divide $c$.
What would be a convincing proof of that using elementary number theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof without prime factorization. Use the Euclidean algorithm to write
$$1=ma+nb \quad\text{for some integers } m,n.$$
Then $c=mac+nbc$. Can you prove that $ab$ divides $c$ now?

Comment: Maybe is better just to write full answer, because if OP could not prove the previous lemma, this will only confuse him even more.

Comment: @1b3b: I'll let the OP respond.

Comment: I am fine using Bezout's Lemma but I fail to see how I can use $c = mac+nbc$ to arrive at the proof

Comment: OK, @Marcus. Can you show that $ab$ divides $mac$? Think carefully.

Comment: Thank you. I can see it now.

Comment: Well done! Using Bezout's Lemma is a super powerful tool in elementary number theory.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the prime factorisation of $c$, use the fact that the prime factorisation any divisor of $c$ can only contain primes in the prime factorisation of $c$.